# How to switch Vue.js to production mode in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

Since Vue.js is comes already installed in Laravel, I'm not sure how to set it to production mode.

When I launch my website I get the message in console:

> You are running Vue in development mode.
>   Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just build your assets using “npm run production”

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like this and thats why I couldn't find it anywhere. Thank you

Answer (score 18):

Method 1

```
npm run production
```

Method 2
In Laravel, add an environment variable in laravel configuration and based on the load the Vue configurations in the run time.

Define: `MIX_ENV_MODE=production`

Usage: `process.env.MIX_ENV_MODE`

And finally, add this code in any of your configuration script files

```
if (process.env.MIX_ENV_MODE === 'production') {
    Vue.config.devtools = false;
    Vue.config.debug = false;
    Vue.config.silent = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setup Manual  app.js before new Vuew

```
Vue.config.productionTip = true
Vue.config.devtools = true;
Vue.config.debug = true;
Vue.config.silent = true;
```

Using npm prod/dev

```
"npm run prod / production"
"npm run dev / watch"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Vue2` with `Laravel7` I get error `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`  when I run `npm run prod`,

and this is the full error.

```
> @ prod /var/www/html/exptradies
> npm run production


> @ production /var/www/html/exptradies
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js


<--- Last few GCs --->

[3521:0x302b050]   110565 ms: Mark-sweep 489.2 (517.6) -> 485.0 (517.6) MB, 1150.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.155, current mu = 0.100) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[3521:0x302b050]   111997 ms: Mark-sweep 489.2 (517.6) -> 485.0 (517.6) MB, 1222.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.150, current mu = 0.146) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x384b92cc08d1 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: concat(this=0x0871a8909981 <JSArray[0]>,0x0871a8909961 <JSArray[0]>,0x0871a8909981 <JSArray[0]>)

    1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x20144909fd61] [/var/www/html/exptradies/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:~1] [pc=0x21c8562eee7d](this=0x349882d804b1 <undefined>,0x3c3d355838b9 <AST_Call map = 0x1ea8d45e1279>,0x0871a89...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa1ae50 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa1b25c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb9b20e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb9b589 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd58815  [node]
 6: 0xd58ea6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd65765 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd66615 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd690cc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xd2f752 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithAllocationSite(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::AllocationSite>) [node]
11: 0xd3b104 v8::internal::Factory::NewJSArrayWithUnverifiedElements(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>, v8::internal::ElementsKind, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
12: 0xd3b549 v8::internal::Factory::NewJSArray(v8::internal::ElementsKind, int, int, v8::internal::ArrayStorageAllocationMode, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
13: 0xec65c3 v8::internal::ElementsAccessor::Concat(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Arguments*, unsigned int, unsigned int) [node]
14: 0xc0a565  [node]
15: 0xc12dfd v8::internal::Builtin_ArrayConcat(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
16: 0x140e919  [node]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-02T16_32_12_621Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-02T16_32_12_662Z-debug.log
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error.